# Need to submit form multiple times with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms

As the title says I need to submit a form multiple times, form's action is an external php file. The form submits once but I need it to submit once with each loop.

```
   function send_sms(){
    var receivers = document.getElementById('receivers').value.toString();
    var receivers_array = receivers.split(',');
    for(var i = 0; i < receivers_array.length; i++) {
        // Trim the excess whitespace.
        receivers_array[i] = receivers_array[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
        document.getElementById('receiver').value = receivers_array[i];
        document.getElementById("smsForm").submit();


    }
}
```

What the code is basically supposed to do is split up phone numbers that the user enters and send a text message to each of the numbers. It submits and a text is sent to the first number in the array but not the other entered numbers. Spliting and everything works(I've used console.log on everything to check). The loop isn't interrupted either because it console logged each receiver value after assigning it inside the loop.

**UPDATE: Got it working like this**

```
  function send_sms(){
    var receivers = document.getElementById('receivers').value.toString();
    console.log(receivers);
    var receivers_array = receivers.split(',');
    console.log(receivers_array[0]);
    for(var i = 0; i < receivers_array.length; i++) {
        // Trim the excess whitespace.
        receivers_array[i] = receivers_array[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
        document.getElementById('receiver').value = receivers_array[i];
        console.log(document.getElementById('receiver').value);
        //document.getElementById("smsForm").submit();
        $.ajax({
            url:'../API/sendsms.php',
            type:'post',
            data:$('#smsForm').serialize(),
            success:function(){
                alert("worked");
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: try ajax. While submit reroutes to php all pending js will be halted. Better do it with ajax. Mind the async logic and all :)

Answer (score 1):

Submit triggers page reload/redirect to your action. You have to add ajax listener for your form submit so it won't refresh the page every time the submit triggers.

```js
$(document).on('submit', 'form#smsForm', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    type: $(this).attr('method'),
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('Submitted');
    },
    error: function(xhr, err) {
      console.log('Error');
    }
  });
  return false;
});

function send_sms() {
  var receivers = document.getElementById('receivers').value.toString();
  var receivers_array = receivers.split(',');
  for (var i = 0; i < receivers_array.length; i++) {
    // Trim the excess whitespace.
    receivers_array[i] = receivers_array[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
    document.getElementById('receiver').value = receivers_array[i];
    document.getElementById("smsForm").submit();


  }
}
```

Comment: This solution seems like what I'm looking for but it doesn't seem to work unfortunately, nothing gets logged in the console either. Still only submits the first number.

Answer (score -1):

You can try collect all numbers and send them in one request, after this parse them on backend side and send sms